# link tag with id element doesnt work in asp.net webpage

Tags: javascript, html, asp.net

The following line of code doesnt work in asp.net website, how do i get the webpage to work?

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css" id="main-styles-link">
```

It doesnt like id the part "id="main-styles-link"".

Because on the designer file it shows

```
    protected global::System.Web.UI.HtmlControls.HtmlLink main-styles-link;
```

and this is highlighted as error..

Severity    Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
Error   CS1003  Syntax error, ',' expected  WebApplication12    C:\Users\Dipesh.Patel\source\repos\WebApplication12\WebApplication12\WebForm1.aspx.designer.cs  22  Active
Error   CS1002  ; expected  WebApplication12    C:\Users\Dipesh.Patel\source\repos\WebApplication12\WebApplication12\WebForm1.aspx.designer.cs  22  Active
Error   CS1519  Invalid token '-' in class, struct, or interface member declaration WebApplication12    C:\Users\Dipesh.Patel\source\repos\WebApplication12\WebApplication12\WebForm1.aspx.designer.cs  22  Active
Error   CS1519  Invalid token '-' in class, struct, or interface member declaration WebApplication12    C:\Users\Dipesh.Patel\source\repos\WebApplication12\WebApplication12\WebForm1.aspx.designer.cs  22  Active
Error   CS1519  Invalid token ';' in class, struct, or interface member declaration WebApplication12    C:\Users\Dipesh.Patel\source\repos\WebApplication12\WebApplication12\WebForm1.aspx.designer.cs  22  Active
Error   CS1519  Invalid token ';' in class, struct, or interface member declaration WebApplication12    C:\Users\Dipesh.Patel\source\repos\WebApplication12\WebApplication12\WebForm1.aspx.designer.cs  22  Active
Error   IDE1007 The name 'styles' does not exist in the current context.    WebApplication12    C:\Users\Dipesh.Patel\source\repos\WebApplication12\WebApplication12\WebForm1.aspx.designer.cs  22  Active
Error   IDE1007 The name 'link' does not exist in the current context.  WebApplication12    C:\Users\Dipesh.Patel\source\repos\WebApplication12\WebApplication12\WebForm1.aspx.designer.cs  22  Active

Comment: Change the - to _ in the id?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use

```
id="mainStylesLink"
```

instead of:

```
id="main-styles-link"
```